# Change Twitter name and icon to X on the profile page

Tags: discussion, twitter

[The Twitter name and logo has been changed to X](https://www.theverge.com/2023/7/24/23804973/twitter-x-logo-brand-replacement). It should be updated on the profile page as well.

[Here's an SVG to use.](https://seeklogo.com/vector-logo/492397/twitter-x)

Comment: I was hoping that the SVG link was a troll :-(

Comment: wasn't there a discussion recently that link to twitter in profile page should be removed entirely?

Comment: Let's wait until twitter manages to change the logo on all of their own sites and decides on the correct color first. Their about page still has the bird logo, the start page uses the x in blue and in black. The identicon has a white X on black background.

Comment: @BDL I assume the icon would be recolored on the profile page just like the current one, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Hardly seems worth making changes to follow twitter's ridiculous death-throes.

Comment: Related over on MSE: [Is it time to reconsider the Twitter link in user profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391139)

Comment: In additional to everything else, they appear to have changed only the company name and logo. The site/app itself (in, for example, the page title or the search bar, their iOS and Android apps, etc.) appears to still be called "Twitter".

Comment: @RyanM Not anymore.

Answer (score 44):

Let's just remove the Twitter section from Stack Exchange profiles, instead. It hasn't been a worthwhile social media site for ~9 months now.

Comment: Related: [staff's answer to 'Add a Mastodon link in addition to Twitter?'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383635/241919)

Comment: If this answer does not get to +200 upvotes, I am going to push the red button.

Comment: See [Is it time to reconsider the Twitter link in user profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391139/is-it-time-to-reconsider-the-twitter-link-in-user-profiles)