Profile does not accept x.com links and shows outdated Twitter/X label and logo
I came across an issue while updating my Stack Overflow profile. Since Twitter has rebranded to X, I noticed a major as well as crucial inconsistency and issue in the "Twitter link or username" section of the profile settings:

The label still says “Twitter link or username”, which is outdated. Ideally, it should be updated to something like “Twitter/X link or username” to reflect the rebranding.
The logo displayed next to the field is still the old Twitter bird icon. This should be replaced with the new X logo.
The validation does not accept links to x.com (e.g., https://x.com/DalsaniaDd), which is now the official domain for Twitter/X.

I think this issue occurs because:

The Regular expression to validate a link is not updated to accept
either a twitter or an X.com link.

Steps to Reproduce:

Go to your profile edit page on Stack Overflow.
Enter a valid X profile link, e.g., https://x.com/YourUsername, in the "Twitter link or username" field.
Click “Save Profile”.
Observe the error message as mentioned below.

Screenshot:

Expected Behavior:

The label should be updated to "Twitter/X link or username."
The logo should be updated to the X logo.
Validation should accept links to x.com too.

Actual Behavior:

The label says "Twitter link or username.
The old Twitter bird icon is displayed as the logo.
Validation does not accept x.com links, making it impossible to save valid X profile URLs.

Environment:
Browser: Any Browser

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425731

Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/405007/twitter-field-on-user-profiles-doesnt-recognize-new-domain-for-service

I tried putting my bsky profile link and it didn't work either :( (Yes, this is meant to be meant "silly".)

People are downvoting this (not fair) because they hate X/Twitter (as they should), but it should be a quick and easy fix so +1 from me at least.

I don't think anyone has said they "downvoted because they hate twitter" here, @JeremyBanks . I've not voted on this, but admittedly, I'd like to see the Twitter link go, but to be replaced by a "Social" link, which the user could have to what ever they want; Facebook, LinkedIn, The Platform formally known as Twitter, BSky, TikTok, etc, etc, or an arbitrary website.
